# Transparency and Right-To-Left support

Tags: java-me, transparency, midp, midp-2.0

I am developing an application using Java ME targeting **MIDP 2.0** devices.

1. Does MIDP 2.0 support transparent PNGs and transparency ?
2. Does LWUIT support RTL support ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. for MIDP 2.0 support of transparency i think it depends on the MIDP implementation
   on the actual device (mostly it doesn't).
2. yes. LWUIT latest version does support RTL.

Answer (score 1):

for transparency support, the API specification for [Display.numAlphaLevels()](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#numAlphaLevels()) method gives quite comprehensive explanation.

Support of PNG format is specified in details in javadocs for `lcdui.Image` class (there's section called *PNG Image Format*)